# How to create a .conf file on the fly in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a proprietary command-line program that I want to call in a bash script.  It has several options in a .conf file that are not available as command-line switches.  I can point the program to any .conf file using a switch, `-F`.

I would rather not manage a .conf file separate from this script.  Is there a way to create a temporary document to use a .conf file?

I tried the following:

`echo setting=value|my_prog -F -`

But it does not recognize the `-` as stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `/dev/stdin` instead of `-`.

You can also use a here document:

```
my_prog -F /dev/stdin <<OPTS
opt1 arg1
opt2 arg2
OPTS
```

Finally, you can let bash allocate a file descriptor for you (if you need stdin for something else, for example):

```
my_prog -F <(cat <<OPTS
opt1 arg1
opt2 arg2
OPTS
)
```

Comment: I went for `my_prog -F <(echo setting=value)`.  It worked and this is a simple one-liner.  I always thought `<(echo setting=value)` meant go to stdin..nope.

Comment: Also, I like this solution since I don't have to worry about if `fd=3` was used elsewhere like my answer.

Answer (score 3):

When writing this question, I figured it out and thought I would share:

```
exec 3< <(echo setting=value)
my_prog -F /dev/fd/3
```

It reads the #3 file descriptor and I don't need to manage any permissions or worry about deleting it when I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYTMPFILE=/tmp/_myfilesettings.$$

cat <<-! > $MYTMPFILE
    somekey=somevalue
    someotherkey=somevalue
!
my_prog -F $MYTMPFILE
rm -f $MYTMPFILE
```

This uses what is known as a "here" document, in that all the contents between the "cat <<-!" up to ! is read in verbatim as stdin. The '-' in that basically tells the shell to remove all leading tabs.

You can use anything as the "To here" marker, e.g., this would work as well:

```
cat <<-EOF > somewhere
     stuff
     more stuff
EOF
```

Comment: Actually the hyphen only tells the shell to remove contiguous leading tabs (not spaces). `Tab-tab-space-tab-foo` would become `space-tab-foo` and `space-space-bar` would become `space-space-bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use process substitution for this:

```
my_prog -F <(command-that-generates-config)
```

where `command-that-generates-config` can be something like `echo setting=value` or a function.